# How to sort arrays of Vector3's positions from left to right?

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, nearest-neighbor

I have an array of 50 million Vector3's stored in a float array of threes. I can convert to and from Vector3 type array.

I wish to sort the array from low to high in C# on the Y axis. It would be good to have an fast and efficient process. I can't find any specific routines for this kind of task, am i missing some keywords to search with? Do i have to write a routine, is there a ready made up one?

Any info would be very appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Just sort the array using a custom comparer that compares on the Y axis. the built in `Array.Sort` function is already fairly fast. Also, is it feasable to insert the data in to the array in a pre-sorted way by doing some sort of pre-processing on whatever your data source is?

Comment: Hi, The data is from linear scans of spacial info in X Y Z directions of space which contains fairly random data, i have to re-order it a bit to analyse it faster. when I was programming synths we had amplitude sort maths called bubble sort and that kind of thing, I'll try some different search terms to find some custom sort code.

Comment: I suggest you try out a simple [Array.Sort(Array, IComparer)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aw9s5t8f(v=vs.110).aspx) and ser if the performance is good enough.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this using an array version of the mathematical pigeonhole sort method:

If array values are discrete or can be rounded to less than a million different values, It can be done in a second for 10 million value arrays.

example for sorting Z of vector3, it rewrites vertex and normal arrays, hence 6 rewrite entries:

```
function Zsort():IEnumerator{
yield WaitForFixedUpdate( );


        var countarr : int[] = new int[3000] ;      
        var loi = 0   ;
        var hii = 0   ; print("z1sort"); WaitForFixedUpdate() ;
    for ( var i : int = 0; i < sortarr.Length ; i++)
    {
        sortarr [ i ] = 0; //Init sort arrays with zeros
        stepsarr[ i ] = 0; //increment beginning of next section
        countarr[ i ] = 0; //used for keeping track of where to write into section for every int
    }print("z2sort"); WaitForFixedUpdate() ;
    for (  i  = 0; i < v1.Length-3 ; i+=3)
    {
        sortarr[ v1[i+2] ] += 1;    // write all positions to sort arrays
    }print("z3sort"); WaitForFixedUpdate() ;
    var indexcount = 0;//used to accumulate index position 0,10,20,30 if all vals have 10 dupes
    for (  i  = 0; i < sortarr.Length ; i++)// 
    {
        stepsarr[ i ] = indexcount; // write staircase section start positions 
        indexcount += sortarr [ i ];
    }   print("z4sort"); WaitForFixedUpdate() ;
    for (  i  = 0; i < v1.Length-3 ; i+=3)
    {   
        v2[ stepsarr[ v1[i+2] ]*3 + countarr[ v1[i+2] ]*3   ] = v1[i  ];    
        v2[ stepsarr[ v1[i+2] ]*3 + countarr[ v1[i+2] ]*3+1 ] = v1[i+1];
        v2[ stepsarr[ v1[i+2] ]*3 + countarr[ v1[i+2] ]*3+2 ] = v1[i+2];
        n2[ stepsarr[ v1[i+2] ]*3 + countarr[ v1[i+2] ]*3   ] = n1[i  ];    
        n2[ stepsarr[ v1[i+2] ]*3 + countarr[ v1[i+2] ]*3+1 ] = n1[i+1];
        n2[ stepsarr[ v1[i+2] ]*3 + countarr[ v1[i+2] ]*3+2 ] = n1[i+2];

        countarr[ v1[i+2] ] += 1 ;
    }   print("z5sort"); WaitForFixedUpdate() ;
    for (  i  = 0; i < v1.Length ; i+=1) 
    {
        v1[ i ] = v2[ i ];  
        n1[ i ] = n2[ i ];  
    }   print("z6sort"); WaitForFixedUpdate() ;


}
```